# Move only 2 matchsticks to find the equality

Tags: matches

Just move two matchsticks to find the equality in the equation below:

Note: There are two reasonable answers.

[image]

Comment: Can I add a match, and only move one?

Comment: @Mithrandir just by moving.

Comment: I can do it by moving one...

Comment: @Will go for it! wondered how :)

Comment: Is making a "non-equal" reasonable? :)

Comment: Move $0$ matches: read it in base $45$.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Dont you mean base 35? This would be a move 0 and move 2 matches answer because you could move one anywhere and put it back.

Comment: No, it'd be base 45 (14 read in base 45 is 49 in base ten; 14 read in base 35 is 39 in base ten)

Comment: @akadian No, they are looking for an equality, not an inequality.  So no <, >,  !=, etc.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Moving two:

> <del>Rotate table 180°</del> Walk around the table and:
>
>  [image: 111 = CXI]
>
>  (matches moved: horizontal bar in the 4, horizontal bar in left 7)

Comment: yes this is what I was looking for and a proper answer :)

Comment: I should have seen this one sooner hahaha

Comment: Can you explain what you see on this picture. Because I see `111 = c * 1`.

Comment: @talex 111 = CXI (Roman numeral for 111)

Comment: Isn't rotating the table moving _all_ the matches?

Comment: @vascowhite We could interpret the puzzle to be us (the solvers) sitting across from Oray (the asker), so really we just need to answer from their perspective rather than ours. We could just as easily walk around it.

Comment: @Will Ah, yes, you are right.

Comment: If one flips the table, only one match need be moved to make 61=LXI, though one could nudge another match slightly just for the fun of it.

Comment: @supercat Yup, that was exactly what I had [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37636/move-only-2-matchsticks-to-find-the-equality#comment111923_37636) but it's a wonky lookin' six.

Comment: @Will: It "matches" the six that was produced by a common seven-segment display driver chip, and has thus been used by a lot of devices for many years.  If you move a second match, the six could be improved by slanting the top.

Answer (score 36):

Another way moving $2$:

> [image]
>  i.e. $\frac77=1^4$

Or similarly:

> [image]
>  i.e $1\times1=1^4$

Comment: Or alternatively, you could use the two sticks to extend the "1" downward, on the RHS, making the 4 look like a proper superscript.

Answer (score 14):

Yet another way moving $2$:

> [image]
>  i.e $7\times7=IL^I$ using Roman numerals on the right hands side: $IL^I=49^1$

Comment: wow i am impressed, great answer!

Comment: The charts I've seen suggest that subtraction by prefix is only applicable for producing 4, 9, 40, 90, 400, 900, or similar larger values using over-bar notation.  The value 49 is properly written as 40+9, (XLIX), not 50-1 (IL).  Similarly, 1999 is 1000+900+90+9, (MCMXCIX), not 2000-1 (MIM).

Comment: @supercat yeah you're correct, it's not in the recognised "standard" form of XLIX; but it wasn't standardised until long, long after the Roman empire. IL is nothing other than 49 (in fact there is also evidence of double subtractive notation being used too, such as XIIX for 18, which is even more confusing).

Answer (score 13):

Well you can do that by

> [image]

How

> The green line is the moved matchsticks. My drawing is not good, though.

Answer (score 9):

Although, I personally feel that Will seems to have the best solution.
We may even do this by removing 2 matches.

> [image: 2*2=4]

Answer (score 4):

> Moving either the leftmost or the rightmost matches making up the X to
>  between the two digits 1 and 4 gives 2 different equations using
>  boolean algebra
>
>   7>7 = 1 > 4
>   7<7 = 1 > 4

in both cases

> the boolean value of both LHS and RHS simplify to false resulting in
>   the equations simplifying to   false = false

i.e. with both sides being equal.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.SE. Although your answer might seem ok as [`lateral-thinking`](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking), but you need to "find the equality" :)

Comment: I think you need to reread my answer - it is expressed as a logic equation i.e. both the LHS and the RHS are equal
To clarify taking the first example 
LHS expression is 7>7 - this simplifies to FALSE
RHS expression 1>4 - this also simplifies to FALSE
This means the whole equation simplifies to FALSE = FALSE - and that is the equality

Comment: I read you answer thrice before editing. There is no clear evidence that you used any function to calculate the Boolean value of the expressions of both LHS and RHS, which would thus make them equivalent, which is not obvious in your case. And as the saying goes, "The absence of evidence isn't the evidence of absence itself."

Comment: Also, you need to re-read your answer(under "in both cases") and look for the explanation I put in so, False=False is True :)

Comment: I agree with this answer, $False=False$ and $x>y$ is a boolean expression

Answer (score 3):

Moving only ONE match:

> [image]

And rotating 180 degrees:

> [image]
>
>  We get 61 = LXI (61 in roman)

Answer (score 2):

I feel like the simplest answer is just to

> move the two matches in the equals sign to make it a greater than sign :
>  7x7 > 14

Comment: This finds an *in*equality.

Answer (score 0):

So how about just:

> Make use of the fact that they are matches!
>  Take the top match of the first digit, making the 7 into a 1.
>  Add the match you took to somewhere in the last digit.
>  Then take top of the second digit, making also that 7 into a 1.
>  But before you also add that match to somwhere in the last digit,
>  LIGHT THE MATCH, and when the fire is out, you will have:
> `.`
> `.     _      _`
> `.      | \/   | _  | |_|    INTO     | \/   | _  |`
> `.      | /\   | _  |   |             | /\   | _  |`

Comment: Clever answer, but please read the [tour].

Comment: @wizzwizz4 what do you think I missed from the tour?

Comment: Nothing in particular, just that you hadn't read the tour. I have even less reputation than you here, so you must be doing something better than me! :-)

Answer (score -1):

Without attempting to draw a picture ...

> If I take 2 matches from the X and move them to the =, I get
>  7/7 ≠ 14

Comment: Yes, but the question is "to find the equality". Yours is an inequality.

Answer (score -1):

7*7 = 49, we can count in ${\mathbb Z}_{10}$ ( or in normal language "only save last digit" ), and then only move the 2 sticks in the "1" in 14 to make a 9 out of the 4.